AWS Managed Grafana timing out when retrieving data from Athena
We have set up Managed Grafana on AWS, installed the necessary plugin, and set up Athena as the data source.
When we run a query in Grafana, we can see it in Athena (in the recent queries tab), and we can see the results in S3 as well, so I don't think it's a permission issue when talking to these services.
On Grafana's side, the query just times out most of the time. Sometimes, once every 20 runs or so, it manages to get and show the data in Grafana, so I know the whole pipeline works.
Has anyone ran into this issue before?

So the issue in the end was that we were using our public subnets in the network access tab. We changed it to use our private subnets, and now every thing is working as intended

Facing same issue, could you add a screenshot how you did?
